# Selecting item from list in mathematica

Tags: list, select, wolfram-mathematica, rules

I have a big list of rules in Mathematica, but I want to select the item that corresponds to certain criteria. Although I've been trying to use the Select and Take commands, I have been unable to get the desired output..

Example: Suppose I want to select the item from the list where A->1.2.

```
list={{A->1,B->2.1,C->5.2},{A->1.1,B->2.6,C->5.5},{A->1.2,B->2.7,C->5.7},{A->1.3,B->2.9,C->6.1}};
```

The desired output would be
    {A->1.2,B->2.7,C->5.7}

I know it is possible to select items from lists, based on their value. But how do I do it from a list of rules?

Thanks

EDIT: apparently, Cases does the trick:

Cases[list, {A-> # | A-> Rationalize[#], 
    Rule[_, _] ..}] & /@ {1.2}

This also searches for numbers in rational and non-rational form, which was another problem I found.

Comment: It might be worth checking out the beta site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ for future Mathematica questions.

Comment: Hi Sosi, if you like **Perl** and mathematics you will love [**PDL**](http://pdl.perl.org) **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The desired output would be {A->1.2,B->2.7,C->5.7}"
So the above answers should be flattened :)

```
Cases[N@mylist, {___, A -> 1.2, ___}] // Flatten
```

Use N to translate things like 6/5 into 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `Select`

For example

```
Select[mylist, MemberQ[#, A -> 1] &]
```

gives

> (* {{A -> 1, B -> 2.1, C -> 5.2}}*)

Other examples;

```
Select[mylist, MemberQ[#, A -> 1.1 |  1.2] &]

Select[mylist, 
 MemberQ[#, A -> 1.1 |  1.2 | 1.3] && FreeQ[#, C -> 6.1] &]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative:

```
Select[list, A == 1.2 /. # &]
```

The advantage of this solution is that it uses `Equal` instead of `MatchQ` (or equivalent).  `1.2 == 6/5` gives `True` (comparison in the mathematical sense) while `MatchQ[1.2, 6/5]` gives `False` (structural comparison).  Of course it's always possible to do `MatchQ[1.2, x_ /; x == 6/5]` to work around this.

Also, this solution ignores the order of rules in the lists.

Comment: Thanks!
Indeed, using your suggestion avoids having to include `Rationalize`.
Yet, I am still to understand how having `Equal` under the criteria of `Select` allows finding rules.

Comment: @SosiKun Look up `ReplaceAll` in the docs.  I used the `/.` operator to substitute `A` with whatever is in the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `Cases`:

`Cases[list, {A -> 1.2, ___}]`

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
Pick[#, A /. #, 1.2]& @ list
```